# what will be the mime type for java application if I want to show both image and html content?

Tags: jsp, servlets, mime, mime-types

In my java web application i need to show the image that exits in the database as well as a 
anchor tag for moving to another jsp page.

In my jsp page it is mentioned `response.setContentType("image/jpg;");`

So while running the jsp page is shows the image but do not show the html below or anywhere.

What i want that my jsp page **should show the image as well as html content at a single jsp page.** So please tell `what mime type should i use` so that to get desire result.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is twofold. First, you send a HTML-page that contains the IMG-tag with the appropriate reference to the source image. Of course this can be surrounded by an A-tag. That page should be of `text/html`.

Secondly, you return the image. This is a separate call to the server. That call should be of `image/jpg`.

Comment: But what else if you need to use both html and image at same single jsp page.

Comment: @satya: it's two different requests to the server. The HTML contains an IMG-tag, not the image itself. The image is sent out separately on a separate request from the client.

Answer (score 1):

Mime types in HTML headers are intended to help browser distinguish between types of binary content transferred from the server. So, if you transfer just HTML, you should specify text/html. You should use image/jpg only if you transfer image binary data to browser using this page.

Comment: But what else if you need to use both html and image at same single jsp page

Comment: You need two separate pages - one contains html code, and other serves image (it's worth to use servlet for this purpose). First page should refer to second one in `img` tag `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="image" src="./ShowImage">
```

This will help to show the image as it pass it to the servlet that have the code for displaying image.

And below the above code you write any html code which also can be seen at the same single jsp page.